# How to show full page title hierarchy

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, navigation

I am navigating through several documents,and i noticed that the top page title doesnt show the full navigation hiearchy.

[image]

When i click on a document in tylers the "Domestic" dissapear
[image]

What i want is the page title to show
Domestic->Tylers->Bank Statement

UPDATED:
i used the answer below using the javascript method but whenever i click on a document set,the document library containing the documents sets shows up twice.[note am using the classic experience]
[[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni7P7.png)

[image]

Comment: see this https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1080535/Adding-Breadcrumb-in-SharePoint

Comment: @AtishDipongkor am facing a problem with document set now. see updated questions to see image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are having your document sets at level 3, you will have to skip the level 3 concatenation in the script:

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilEventNotified(addBreadcrumb, "sp.bodyloaded");

function addBreadcrumb() 
{
    if (!document.querySelector("#pageTitle span span span")) {
        document.querySelector("#pageTitle").style.display = 'block';
        return;
 }

var elementsInPageTitle = document.querySelector("#pageTitle span").outerHTML;
var breadcrumbDivider = '<span style="height:16px;width:16px;position:relative;display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;"><img src="/_layouts/15/images/spcommon.png?rev=42" alt=":" style="position:absolute;left:-109px !important;top:-232px !important;"/></span>';
var allBreadcrumbElements = "";

var siteTitle = _spPageContextInfo.webTitle;
var elementIsExistsPageTitle = function(el) {
    return [].some.call(document.querySelectorAll
    ("#pageTitle span span span"), function(sEl) {
        return el.innerText == sEl.innerText;
    });
};

var breadcrumbClassName = "";

if (document.querySelectorAll(".s4-breadcrumb li a").length) {
    breadcrumbClassName = ".s4-breadcrumb li a";
} else {
    breadcrumbClassName = ".ms-breadcrumb li a";
}

var indexOfTheLastElement = document.querySelectorAll(breadcrumbClassName).length - 1;
var count =1;
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(breadcrumbClassName), function(el, index) {
    if(count!=3)
    {
        if (!(index == indexOfTheLastElement && elementIsExistsPageTitle(el))) {
                    allBreadcrumbElements += '<span>' + 
                    el.outerHTML + '</span>' + breadcrumbDivider;   

        }
}

    count++;    

});

allBreadcrumbElements += elementsInPageTitle;

document.querySelector("#pageTitle").innerHTML = allBreadcrumbElements;
document.querySelector("#pageTitle").style.display = 'block';
```

}

Answer (score 3):

I believe you cannot change this through configuration and you may have to modify the master page through designer etc

Check [this](https://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2015/08/sharepoint-2013-breadcrumb/)

Comment: can you show me an implementation of it,i cant figure where to put the codes.

Answer (score 1):

This blog works:https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1080535/Adding-Breadcrumb-in-SharePoint

Note:the breadcrumb.js file at line 11,the image tag need to be close.